# Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays:

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am attempting to make a multilayer model with the functional API from keras. The idea is to take an vector that describes an image (comes from a pretrained model) and concatenate it with another vector that comes from the text associated with that image. The first branch processes the input coming from the images, the second branch takes as input the text. Both are concatenated and then processed together with a few more layers.

When I train the model with:

```
model = Model(inputs=[xa.input, xb.input], outputs=z)
```

and this fit call:

```
model.fit([oraciones_img, X], y, epochs=2, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
```

everything works out fine.

The problem comes when I want to do a prediction. I provided two arrays with the same dimensions as oraciones_img and X to the model.predict function but it throws this error:

---

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays: [array([[1.1081828 , 0.4828459 , 1.6334529 , ..., 0.03270344, 0.17258629,
    0.03792314],
   [0.8138524 , 0.        , 0.65887845, ..., 0.6183274 , 0.00807555,
    0.6506448 ],
   [0.8...
```

---

I double checked that the dimensions from the inputs during training and testing are the same but did not work out. I tried the training data on the predict function, assuming that at least that should work out, but weirdly that throws the same error. In theory, I should be providing this:

```
model.predict([ (n_samples, 405504) , (n_samples, 50) ])
```

where:
(n_samples, 405504) are the vectors coming from n images
(n_samples, 50)     are the vectors coming from n texts associated to the images

but somehow the model is asking me for a single array. I provided one to follow up, and the predict function is asking for a single array of dim4 which is a bit more confusing.

I have seen other posts regarding similar issues on the shape of the data, but all of them have problems running the fit function. I already passed that, this is about the predict function.

Any idea of what is going on?

## define model

```
seq_length = 50
seq_length_img = (200704 + 2048)*2

InputA = Input(shape=(seq_length_img,))
InputB = Input(shape=(seq_length,))

xa = Dense(512, activation='relu')(InputA)
xa = Model(inputs = InputA, outputs= xa)

xb = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=512, input_length=seq_length)(InputB)
xb = Flatten()(xb)
xb = Dense(512, activation='relu')(xb)
xb = Model(inputs = InputB, outputs= xb)

combined = concatenate([xa.output, xb.output], axis=-1)
combined = Reshape((1024, 1))(combined)

z = LSTM(1024, input_shape=(1024, 1), return_sequences=True)(combined)
z = LSTM(1024)(z)
z = Dense(100, activation='relu')(z)
z = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(z)

model = Model(inputs=[xa.input, xb.input], outputs=z)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([oraciones_img, X], y, epochs=2, batch_size=5, verbose=1)

yhat = model.predict([feat, pred_sentence])
```

Comment: Can you print the value of model.inputs ?

Comment: what happens if you call model.predict with the training data: `model.predict([oraciones_img, X])`?

Comment: Hi Matias! This is the output [<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 405504) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'input_2:0' shape=(?, 50) dtype=float32>]

Comment: Hi @Stewart_R , same error as with the test data

Comment: I get the feeling that you somehow overwrote the model variable with a different model that only takes one input, if that happened we have no way of knowing.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thank you for your comments! I rewrote the main code (what I showed was just a section) and now it works. I think that you were right on your last comment and I had mixed two different models which was leading to this mistake. The input of the mixed model was alright when I trained, but in between that and the prediction, I had called again the pretrained model. Anyway, thank you!